# quantitative winding number?

Tags: gn.general-topology

In light of Tao's discussion of [Quantitative Continuity](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/05/22/quantitative-continuity-estimates/) I've decided to post some thoughts on Winding number.

The Jordan curve theorem is non-trivial because closed curves can be very complicated.  ( Image taken from [Wordpress](https://nebusresearch.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/theorem-thursday-the-jordan-curve-theorem/) )
[image]

I am going to raise two doubts in this discussion.  Mainly the Jordan curve theorem and winding numbers are maybe not robust:

- the red dot as nearby points that inside and other nearby points that are outside.
- if I erase a small segment maybe (maybe on the outside) the curve

Despite being an open curve, I may not have the infinite time or resources to compute a way out.  Is there any way to formalize this notion of **approximate winding number**?

For an open curve we no longer have that the winding number is an integer can we have:

$$ \int_\gamma  d \big( \log \, z \big) \in \mathbb{Z} + [-\epsilon, \epsilon]  $$

for some small number $\epsilon > 0$.  This may still not be a good measure of the ``tangledness" of the curve surrounding the red point.

---

Another example showing these closed curves can be arbitrary.
[image]